# Any way to keep the CTRL + Space dialog box up?

Tags: eclipse

I love the CTRL+ Space dialog box in Eclipse, but it's somewhat frustrating how it closes if you type one letter wrong. Is there any way to keep it up even after making a mistake? It wouldn't even have to show anything in it. It could just resume suggestions after I backspace and start typing again. I just don't want to press CTRL+Space everytime I backspace after making a mistake. (Sounds lazy, I know.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested in http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/FAQ#Can_I_enable_code_completion_to_be_activated_as_I_type_like_how_it_works_in_Visual_Studio.3F